# Could NOT find BOOST_FILESYSTEM (missing: BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES)

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, cmake, nao-robot

I am trying to compile my NAO project.

Every time i run the command `qibuild configure -c mytoolchain`. I get the following error: `Could NOT find BOOST_FILESYSTEM (missing: BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES)`

I am using CMake 3.1, Visual studio 12 (2013) and Python 2.7.

I have been following these steps: `http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/cpp/tutos/using_qibuild.html#cpp-tutos-using-qibuild`

I installed Boost C++ but i have no idea on how to use that (not even sure if that's the solution for my error).

Any tips or comments are appreciated

Comment: Boost components can be header-only, i.e. you do only need the headers, no compilation, no linking required. Boost.Filesystem does not fall into this category: You need to *compile* Boost, and link to the resulting Boost.Filesystem library, in order to use its features. When you say you "installed" Boost, have you done [the compilation steps](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary)?

Comment: Another issue... CMake expects the path to Boost to be provided in a special way, using `-DBOOST_ROOT=...` on the CMake command line. The standard way of adding third-party paths, `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...`, does not work reliably. Since you are not actually using *CMake*, but *qibuild* (which in turn builds on top of CMake but apparently adds a level of indirection during configuration). I have no idea of how to tell `qibuild` to properly add Boost libraries... **EDIT:** Try to set the environment variable `Boost_DIR` to the Boost installation path and re-run the configuration.

Comment: I did both that, after the boost compilation i added it to my PATH variable (i called the prefix "bin" and inside there was a lib folder which i added to the PATH). i also added the Boost installation path to a Boost_DIR environment variable but that didn't solve the error either

Comment: Uh... *how* did you install Boost? I use `.\bootstrap.bat msvc` and `.\b2 -q variant=release,debug address-model=64 --prefix=C:\Boost install` from a Visual Studio Win64 Command Prompt -- and that works fine for me without extending `PATH`, although I am using vanilla CMake, not `qibuild`.

Comment: I used your compilation method, it doesn't change the error message sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you do properly the step 3 from [this piece of documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/1-14/dev/cpp/tutos/using_qibuild.html#creating-code-running-on-your-computer)?
Normally, this should allow qibuild to find boost directly from the NAOqi SDK.
Therefore you should not need to install boost in your system.

Otherwise, is possible that Visual Studio 2013 is supported with the 1.14 version. Please try with Visual Studio 2010.